# matlab surface plot - label colorbar and change axis values

Tags: matlab, graph, label, geometry-surface

I am trying to plot a 3D surface plot in matlab with a colorbar.

I would like to know how to

1. label the title of the colorbar
2. change the axis tick labels

The important parts of my code are

```
number_panels = 1:100:500;
number_turbines = 0;
number_batteries = 0:300:1700;

for idx_number_panels = 1:length(number_panels) 

for idx_number_turbines = 1:length(number_turbines) 

    for idx_number_batteries = 1:length(number_batteries) 

        for h=2:3 %# hours

A = squeeze(total_annual_cost)
B = squeeze(total_renewables_penetration)

figure;
surface(A,B)
```

[image]
I am trying to change the x and y axis ticks from the intervals of the for loop to actual numbers that represent each interval.

I can't seem to find any of the above in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows how to change the Xticks, the Yticks and to add labels to the values of the colorbar:

```
clear all
close all
clc

h = surface(peaks)
colorbar('YTickLabel',...           % set labels to the colorbar
    {'Freezing','Cold','Cool','Neutral',...
     'Warm','Hot','Burning','Nuclear'})
view(-35,45)

number_panels = 0:5:50;
number_batteries = 0:15:50;

set(gca,'XTick',number_panels)      % set Xticks
set(gca,'YTick',number_batteries )  % set Yticks
grid on
```

[image]

With this code you change the first YTickLabel to set a colorbar title (well, something similar):

```
clear all
close all
clc

number_panels = 0:5:50;
number_batteries = 0:15:50;

h = surface(peaks);
chandle = colorbar;

current_colorbar_labels = get(chandle,'YTickLabel');
current_zticks = get(chandle,'YTick');
aux = cellstr(current_colorbar_labels);
aux{end} = 'Title';
set(chandle,'YTickLabel',aux);
view(-35,45)

set(gca,'XTick',number_panels)      % set Xticks
set(gca,'YTick',number_batteries )  % set Yticks
set(gca,'ZTick',current_zticks )  % set Yticks
grid on
```

[image]

My code for the colorbar commands is based on: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html

Hope this helps, I will try to add the title to the colorbar...

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to be doing what I need. I have managed to sort out the legend of the graph. However, I have not managed to mark the numbers on the x and z axis to the numbers I want and not the number I have on the for loop

Comment: also, how can I limit the legend values to be between 0 and 1

Comment: *I have not managed to mark the numbers on the x and z axis to the numbers I want and not the number I have on the for loop* You should be able to do this using the set(gca,'XTick', my_desired_xvalues), with 'Xtick', 'Ytick', 'Ztick'. You tell matlab exactly the vector you want chanhing the third argument of the set command. *how can I limit the legend values to be between 0 and 1*, The values of the colorbar depend on the values you have for the z-axis. If you want to have values in the z-axis between 0 and 1, you should tranform your data before plotting (to make it be between 0 and 1).